# Update document inheriting from ORestricted in OrientDB

Tags: c#, orm, orientdb

I've created a class in OrientDB implementing Record Level Security:

```
create class material;  
alter class  material superclass +ORestricted;  
alter class  material strictmode true;  

create property material.mat_ref string;  
alter property  material.mat_ref mandatory true;  
create property material.mat_locked boolean;
alter property  material.mat_locked mandatory true;  
create property material.mat_active boolean;  
alter property  material.mat_active mandatory true;  
...
```

I try to map this class to a C# class using OrientDB.NET:

```
   public class Material : ODocument
    {
        public Material()
        {
            base.OClassName = GetType().Name.ToLower();
        }

        public string Reference
        {
            get { return GetField<string>("mat_ref"); }
            set { SetField<string>("mat_ref", value); }
        }
   ...
   }
```

Then I get a record from the cluster:

```
var _mat = _db.Select().From<Material>().Where("mat_ref").Like("A%").ToList<Material>().First();
```

After editing any field of the mapped object I want to update its related record in the database:

```
_mat.Reference = "12345";
_db.Update<Material>(_mat).Run();
```

which produces an SQL query string like this one:

```
UPDATE #18:0 SET mat_ref = '12345', mat_locked = False, mat_active = True, _allow = System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.Object]
```

The '_allow' property inherited from ORestricted (type Hashset) is obviously incorrectly serialized and throws an exception when run:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #0: Error parsing query:...
```

I know I could avoid serializing '_allow' by updating just the properties that have changed, but I'd like to make it general. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any workaround?